# error : Object refrence not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

When I want to insert a control in the design form with an error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
What is the solution? Please guide me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9UoD.png)

I expected to add a control in my design form without any error, but unfortunately I encountered an error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Looks like the code which the Windows Forms Designer generates may have become corrupted. If you edit the code from Form1.cs (and Form1.designer.cs if it exists) into your question (as text, not screenshots) then we may be able to work out what is null and why. Alternatively, as it looks like nothing has been added to the form yet, you could delete all the Form1.* files from your project, add a new form and see whether you can drop controls onto the new form.